# Feature Request: Moderator Nomination Encouragement

Tags: feature-request, moderator-elections, election

During moderator nominations, a button/link should be added to user pages to show your support for a user to nominate themselves.

Since you can no longer nominate other users for moderator election, it would be nice to have the ability to encourage other users to nominate themselves.  I propose a button/link added to users pages that can be clicked by other users.  Once clicked a message (similar to the 'you have a new badge') would be displayed to the user on their next login, which would say something like '[User 123] would like to encourage you to run for a moderator position'.

Clicking the banner would take the user to a page where they could either 'Accept' or 'Decline'.  If the user accepts they should be taken to the signup page, if they decline they should no longer be pestered by the messages at login.

Comment: B Mitch would like to encourage you to run for a moderator position :)

Comment: You could encourage them in chat, or maybe even as a comment reply.

Comment: @B Mitch: Thanks for the encouragement, but I'll have to decline. I don't think I want to be a moderator (at least not this time), maybe next time they are looking for mods I will be open to the opportunity.

Comment: @ Rebecca Chernoff: Chat might be a good option if it was more widely used, it doesn't seem to be a heavily used feature on this site.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not opposed to the feature, but as a stopgap measure (since you seem really eager to nominate someone), how about a "Who would you like to see as moderator?" question on Meta?

Comment: It's not that I'm particularly eager to nominate a specific person, just that I would like to see more than 1 candidate.  And I feel like giving people a push might encourage them to nominate themselves.

Comment: @Tester - I'm *thinking* of standing, but want to wait to see which (if any) of the existing pro-temp mods stand first.

Comment: @ChrisF: Don't wait too long, election begins in 5 days.

Comment: @Tester - I know. I'm thinking I should nominate anyway as I can always withdraw.

Comment: I was hoping my nomination would have spawned a collective "anyone but that guy" set of nominations.  Instead I think I killed the party.  Sorry about that.  I'll try harder next time. :)

Comment: I like this answer. Good moderator candidates should be at least passingly familiar with the meta site, so this provides a way to encourage them without any changes to the system itself.